# Mysql return rows for any 12 month period

Tags: mysql

I have a list of phone numbers and the dates that they were called. I ultimately need to return a list of any number that was called more than once in any 12 month period of time.

I know that I could use the below query to return any calls within a calendar year period (but am not sure how to look for any 12 month period)

```
select * from t1 
where (date_sent between '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 00:00:00');
```

I know that I could use the below query to get the count of how many times each number was called

```
select phone, count(*) as count 
from t1 
group by phone 
order by phone;
```

I could put the prior query into a new table and look for count>1 but then I lose out on the dates since the above query returns unique rows by phone number

I am not sure how to return what phone number had more than one call between any 12 month period and not just a calendar year or defined/static period.

Thanks

Comment: What is the primary key in your table? What is the data type of `date_sent`? Can one number be called twice within the same date? Consider to post the table schema. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`.

Comment: There is no primary key unfortunately as this is a list of phone numbers where I had to create a non unique index on the phone number column. The data type of date_sent is DATETIME. A number can be called more than once on the same date.

Comment: Do you have any unique index on the table? As I already wrote: Just run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` and post the result in your question. This is actually required by SO rules, since you should create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where phone = t.phone
    and date_send <> t.date_send
    and abs(datediff(date_send, t.date_send)) <= 365
)
order by t.phone, t.date_send
```

This code will return all phones for which there is another row with a `date_send` that is not more than 365 days away.
If you only need the column `phone` then replace `select t.*` with `select distinct phone` and remove `t.date_send` from the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 2):

First, I want to point out that your between clause misses data from December 31.  A call at noon on December 31 would not be between '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 00:00:00' since these are timestamps.  You need `between '2016-03-21 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-21 00:00:00'`.

For *any* 12 month period, what you really want is "Return all the records where there is a *different* record within 12 months earlier".  To do this, join the table to itself.

```
SELECT t1_curr.phone, t1_curr.date_sent
FROM t1 t1_curr
  INNER JOIN t1 t1_ago
    ON t1_curr.phone = t1_ago.phone
       AND t1_curr.id <> t1_ago.id
       AND t1_ago.date_sent between
           datesub(t1_curr.date_sent, INTERVAL 12 MONTH) and t1_curr.date_sent
```

Comment: This should return all numbers, because every row will be at least joined with itself and have a date difference of zero.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You are right.  I forgot to exclude matching records.  Answer has been edited.